# Clamd cannot start

Tags: centos, centos6, clamav

I am using Centos 6 and clamd (clamav daemon) cannot start:

Here is the error message:

```
Starting Clam AntiVirus Daemon: LibClamAV Error: cli_load(): Can't open file /var/clamav/lmd.user.hdb
LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir(): error loading database /var/clamav/lmd.user.hdb
ERROR: Can't open file or directory
```

Please note that /var/clamav/lmd.user.hdb points to a non-existent file: /usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.runtime.user.14151.hdb

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where did you install clamd from? What do you mean by "points to"? Is there a symlink named `lmd.user.hdb` in your `/var/clamav` directory? Where does that come from? Did you try removing it?

Comment: yes, by "points to" i was referring to a symlink named lmd.user.hdb in the /var/clamav directory. not sure where it came from, so i never want to risk the server by removing it. however, reinstalling maldet helped..pls see below

Comment: i am not exactly know why someone downvoted my question? i thought this is an entirely legitimate question considering that some other people might have run into the same issue too

Comment: The reason is most probably because your question is unclear (omitting essential information like the packages installed) and shows little research effort (not even checking out that symlink with rpm or Google), perhaps also that it appears off topic in Serverfault (giving the impression that yours is not a business environment.) If you edit your question to improve that the downvoter may well take back the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite Tony's very rude answer, and plz check the following link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/676176/clamav-daemon-cant-open-lmd-user-ndb-wont-start

Forcing maldet reinstall solved the problem for me too.

Regards.

Comment: thank you for your help! it worked after maldet was reinstalled..only extra thing i did was to change the permission of the new database files so that clamd can access